# When I swipe a UITableViewCell, the header view moves as well

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I have a few Swipe actions like delete, block, etc in my `UITableView`. I wanted to add headers to separate my two sections. So, I added a prototype cell, named it `HeaderCell` and then went to the view. I added one label, named `headerLabe`. My problem is that when I swipe for the actions, the header cells were moving as well, which looked bad. I researched, and found a solution to just return the contentView of the cell. However, when I do this, the label has not shown up. I have tried a dozen different solutions, and nothing has worked, so I have turned to SO. Can anyone help me?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell : CustomHeaderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderTableViewCell

    if section == 0 {
        headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Thank You's"
    } else if section == 1 {
        headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Conversations"
    }

    return headerCell.contentView
}
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a section Header as @ozgur suggest.If you still want to use a cell.

Refer to this datasource method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath = YourHeaderCellIndexPath{
        return false
    }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**check the following methods**

In your UIViewController use the following

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60

    }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! WishListHeaderCell
            headerCell.lblTitle.text = cartsData.stores_Brand_Name
            let imgVw = UIImageView()
            imgVw.frame = CGRectMake(8, 18, 25, 25)
            imgVw.image = UIImage(named: "location.png")

            let title = UILabel()
            title.frame = CGRectMake(41, 10, headerCell.viwContent.frame.width - 49, 41)
            title.text = cartsData.stores_Brand_Name
            title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            headerCell.viwContent.addSubview(imgVw)
            headerCell.viwContent.addSubview(title)
            return headerCell.viwContent

        }
```

In your UITableViewCell use the following

```
    import UIKit

    class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

         @IBOutlet weak var viwContent: UIView!
         @IBOutlet weak var imgIcn: UIImageView!
         @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!


        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            self.viwContent.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        }

        override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    //UITableViewCell

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as! SecJobCCHeaderTableViewCell

    // Cell Rect
    var cellRect : CGRect = headerCell.frame
    cellRect.size.width = screenBounds.width

    // Header Footer View
    let headerFooterView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(frame : cellRect)

    //Adding Gesture
    let swipeGestRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(AddSecJobCostCentreViewController.draggedViewRight(_:)))
    swipeGestRight.enabled = true
    swipeGestRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    headerFooterView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestRight)

    // Update Cell Rect
    headerCell.frame = cellRect

    // Add Cell As Subview
    headerCell.tag = 1000
    headerFooterView.addSubview(headerCell)

    // Return Header Footer View
    return headerFooterView
}

func draggedViewRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // Swipe Gesture Action
    let currentHeaderView = sender.view?.viewWithTag(1000) as! SecJobCCHeaderTableViewCell


}
```